# div not using available space (div:inline-block, position:fixed)

Tags: css, html, width, fixed

I've got a problem with a div whichis used as a overlay/"popup". I want it to use a max-width of 90% if needed. Unfortunately it always uses around 50% although theres more then enough text to fill the whole screen. But instead of using the width (too) it only stretches it vertically (which is fine). I am trying to avoid a absolute width-attribute because i want some kind of "width: auto;".
These are the relevant/applied styles (copied from the developer console):

```
element.style {
   display: inline-block;
   opacity: 1;
}
@media (min-device-width: 1000px) {
   .Dialog_window {
      max-height: 90%;
      max-width: 90%;
      width: auto;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transition: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -o-transition: translate(-50%,-50%);
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   }
}
.Dialog_window {
   background-color: #EEE;
   padding: 20px;
   border: 1px solid #FFF;
   position: fixed;
   overflow: auto;
   z-index: 100000;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
}

html {
   font-size: 100%;
}
html {
   font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

the Dom-Element is declared like this:
`<div id="myID" class="Dialog_window" style="display: inline-block;"> [...] </div>`

Thank you for any help in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` and `max-height` tell the browser, "take up as much space as you need, but not any more than [x]". You're not forcing the element to occupy 90%, you're saying, "Not more than 90%". Unless you have enough content in the element to take up this space, this is the wrong property to style.

you may want to try using `min-width` and `min-height`, as these tell the browser, "starting at [x], take up this space".

since 90% of an absolutely positioned element is a lot of space, why not just stick with a fixed measurement, like `width: 90%; max-height: 90%;`?

```
   .Dialog_window {
    max-height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

}
If you need a flexible window, that sits within ranges, you should use both `min-width` and `max-width`:

```
       .Dialog_window {
           min-height: 50%;
           max-height: 90%;
           min-width: 50%;
           max-width: 90%
           transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   }
```

Comment: Well yes thats actually what i want: use as less space as possible and a max of 90%. So if it's for example a confirmation popup it should only be a small one (10-15% maybe). In case of a popup Holding lets say some text (e.g. terms of use) it should use the 90% height/width and enable the scrollbar inside the div-tag (the scrollbar works by the way). And im alreasy using "Position:fixed" ;)

Comment: Good to know. so you need a flexible width. I edited my answer to show an example of min-width AND max width.

you may also want to dial down your z-index: 9999 is pretty standard and fairly hard to beat.

Comment: Well i changed the css but unfortunately without any effect. The window/div will still stretch vertically as I exepect it to but refuses to stretch horizontally. It will only use a maximum width of the in min-width declared width and somehow ignores the max-width.

As some kind of workaround I can add a div to the content of the popup with an absolte width but thats not what i actually want.